# Replaced a complete line in text file on a given row number, using shell command

Tags: shell

I need to replace a particular line with a new-text-string ,tried few things but not succeeded.

This is what I did:

1- Get the line number which needs to be replaced using

```
lineNum=$(sed -n '/Old-Line-Text/=' FileName.txt);
```

2- Use the Line number from step 1 to replace that line using

```
sed 'Ns/.*/New-Line-Text/' FileName.txt > FileName2.txt;
```

Now I need to combine these two commands in one commands. Tried certain things But was't able to get it Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better do this :

```
sed '/Old-Line-Text/s/.*/New-Line-Text/' file
```

but this can be resumed as just :

```
sed 's/.*Old-Line-Text.*/New-Line-Text/' file
```